# datatable and change column datatype

Tags: types, datatable, datacolumn

it's not possible to change a datacolumn's DataType property if the DataTable is not empty. Thats ok.

But if I add rows to the DataTable , later remove them so that the DataTable is empty again, I also cannot change the columns datatype.

Is there a way to change the datatype of the column without rebuilding the datatable from scratch and without cloning the datatable?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please accept the answer or comment what you have found further ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do that, even if the data table is populated.
I just did that now in my database.

Comment: I am talking about a system.data.datatable created by code, not about changing a database column in sql server (which does a re-creation of a new table under the covers BTW). When the datatable already has existing rows, the datacolumns type cannot be changed. But even when I empty the datatable, the columns type cannot be changed, it seems that filling the rows locks the columns agains changes regarding type. I look for a way to unlock to columns without rebuilding the datatable